# How to do a loop within a loop vba

Tags: vba, excel

I cannot figure out how to do a loop within a loop.

There is a list of words on sheet 1 that need to be copied and pasted if they match up with any of the 20 desired key words on sheet two, column 1.

This then needs to be copy pasted onto sheet 3. Then I need to look at the same list from sheet 1 and copy paste those onto sheet 4 if they match up with any of the key words from sheet 2, column 2. I could use any help.

Comment: What about showing what you have tried?

Comment: Well I cannot right now as I'm not at the office. I can first thing in the morning

Answer (score 2):

Single loop

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 6
    Cells(i, 1).Value = 100
Next i
```

Double Loop

```
Dim i As Integer, 
Dim j As Integer

For i = 1 To 6
    For j = 1 To 2
        Cells(i, j).Value = 100
    Next j
Next i
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2 loops (which are slow)

Loop through the values in sheet 1 testing if they exists using this:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A20"), Range("A1")) > 0 Then
    'Your copy and paste code goes here for sheet 3
ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B20"), Range("A1")) > 0 Then
    'Your copy and paste code goes here for sheet 4
End If
```

Comment: Hmm this code does not seem to work. It shows a type mismatch on the first line.

Comment: Sorry my bad change range("a1") to range("a1").text

Comment: Now it is saying that the countif is an invalid qualifier

Comment: Sorry got the Countif params back to front, check the modified code.